# How to put Glyphicons Icons in input?

Tags: php, html, zend-framework, zend-framework2

How can I add a Glyphicons Icons in the input below?

A part of the code:

```
class GrupoUsuarioForm{
        $this->setAttributes(array(
            'method' => 'POST',
            'class'  => 'formGrupoUsuario',
            'name'   => 'formGrupoUsuario' 
    ));
    $this->setInputFilter(new GrupoUsuarioInputFilter());    

    $dataCadastro = new Text('data_grp');
    $dataCadastro->setValue(date('d/m/Y'))
    ->setAttributes(array(
    //'style' => 'width: 20%',
    'id', 'dataGrp',
    'readOnly' => 'true'
    ));
    $dataCadastro->setLabel('Data do Cadastro');        
    $this->add($dataCadastro);
```

Would like this return HTML

```
    <label>Textbox with calendar icon</label>
    <div class="input-append"><input type="text" id="" name="">
    <span   class="add-on"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></span></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Where excatly do you want put this icon? 
You can render form's elements as you want.

In controller:

```
public function myAction()
{
    return new ViewModel([
        'form' => new GrupoUsuarioForm()
    ]);
}
```

In your view:

```
// HTML code here
...
<?php $form = $this->form; ?>
<?php $form->prepare(); ?>
<?php echo $this->form()->openTag($form); ?>
...
<?php echo $this->formLabel($form->get('data_grp')); ?>
<div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-append">
        <?php echo $this->formInput($form->get('data_grp')); ?>
        <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></span>
    </div>
</div>
...
<?php echo $this->form()->closeTag(); ?>
```

Comment: I have a class with inputs, the form is not in the phtml page

Comment: How do you use these inputs?

Comment: What you probably want is calendar/date icon next to input? Don't you pass this form class to view later?

Comment: I added how I would like the HTML return

Comment: If you want to render form in another way, you should to create new `Form View Helpers` https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.form.view.helpers.html